# JQuery validation plugin scroll top iframe on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a `form` within an `iframe` of my website.
I'm using the jQuery validation plugin.

The `form` is generated by a `PHP` file and goes through some steps before submitting.
Every step I want the `form` to scroll back to the top of the page as otherwise, the fields are no longer visible.

I've tried about everything:

in the `iframe` tag: `onload="scroll(0,0);"` -> does not work

within the `iframe` itself in the form tag:
   `onsubmit="parent.scrollTo(0, 0); return true"` -> not working

then I tried within the jQuery validation code: (I disabled the
   `focusInvalid` as I read somewhere this could interfere and put
   `window.parent.$("body").animate({scrollTop:0}, 'fast');` in the code.

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#person_A_details').validate({ 
                focusInvalid: false,
                rules: {
                    CONTACTS_EMAIL: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    CONTACTS_LNAME: "required",
                    CONTACTS_FNAME: "required",
                    CONTACTS_GENDER: "required",
                    CONTACTS_PHONE: "required",
                    CONTACTS_LANGUAGE: "required",
                    CONTACTS_FIXEDPARTNER: "required",
                    PRODUCT_SELECT: "required",
                },
                messages: {
                    CONTACTS_FNAME: "<?php echo $FRM_ERRMSG_CONTACTS_FNAME;?>",
                    CONTACTS_LNAME: "<?php echo $FRM_ERRMSG_CONTACTS_LNAME;?>",
                    CONTACTS_GENDER: "<?php echo $FRM_ERRMSG_CONTACTS_GENDER;?>",
                    CONTACTS_PHONE: "<?php echo $FRM_ERRMSG_CONTACTS_PHONE;?>",
                    CONTACTS_LANGUAGE: "<?php echo $FRM_ERRMSG_CONTACTS_LANGUAGE;?>",
                    CONTACTS_FIXEDPARTNER: "<?php echo $FRM_ERRMSG_CONTACTS_FIXEDPARTNER;?>",
                    PRODUCT_SELECT: "<?php echo $FRM_ERRMSG_PRODUCT_SELECT;?>",
                    CONTACTS_EMAIL: {
                      required: "<?php echo $FRM_ERRMSG_CONTACTS_EMAIL;?>",
                      email: "<?php echo $FRM_ERRMSG_CONTACTS_EMAIL_FORMAT;?>"
                    }
                  },
                submitHandler: function (form) { 
                    window.parent.$("body").animate({scrollTop:0}, 'fast');
                    form.submit();  

                }
            });
```

Comment: Have you tried simply `$(document).scrollTop();` in your submit handler? You also should not be calling `form.submit()` in your submit handler, as this method fires after the form has successfully been submitted.

Comment: $(document).scrollTop(); does not do anything, I need to parent frame to scroll to the top as it's an iframe. Not calling the form.submit() results in not submitting the form...